# How to write JavaRDD to marklogic database

Tags: apache-spark, marklogic, marklogic-8

I am evaluating spark with marklogic database. I have read a csv file, now i have a JavaRDD object which i have to dump into marklogic database.

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("org.sparkexample.Dataload").setMaster("local");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    JavaRDD<String> data = sc.textFile("/root/ml/workArea/data.csv");
    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
    JavaRDD<Record> rdd_records = data.map(
      new Function<String, Record>() {
          public Record call(String line) throws Exception {
             String[] fields = line.split(",");
             Record sd = new Record(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2], fields[3],fields[4]);
             return sd;
          }
    });
```

This JavaRDD object i want to write to marklogic database.

Is there any spark api available for faster writing to the marklogic database ?

Lets say, If we could not write JavaRDD directly to marklogic then what is the currect approach to achieve this ?

Here is the code which i am using to write the JavaRDD data to marklogic database, let me know if it is wrong way to do that.

```
final DatabaseClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient("localhost",8070, "MLTest");
    final XMLDocumentManager docMgr = client.newXMLDocumentManager();   
    rdd_records.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<Record>>() {
        public void call(Iterator<Record> partitionOfRecords) {
            while (partitionOfRecords.hasNext()) {
                Record record = partitionOfRecords.next();
                System.out.println("partitionOfRecords - "+record.toString());
                String docId = "/example/"+record.getID()+".xml";
                JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Record.class);
                JAXBHandle<Record> handle = new JAXBHandle<Record>(context);
                handle.set(record);
                docMgr.writeAs(docId, handle);
            }
      }
    });
    client.release();
```

I have used java client api to write the data, but i am getting below exception even though POJO class **Record** is implementing Serializable interface. Please let me know what could be the reason & how to solve that.

> org.apache.spark.sparkexception task not Serializable .

Comment: I don't know much about Spark, but here are some resources that might help: [How to use MarkLogic in Apache Spark applications](http://developer.marklogic.com/blog/marklogic-spark-example); [Putting Spark to Work With MarkLogic](http://www.marklogic.com/resources/putting-spark-work-marklogic/).

Comment: Thanks Dave, i have seen that example. That example is storing the output data to hdfs not to the marklogic database.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get data into MarkLogic is via HTTP and the client REST API - specifically the /v1/documents endpoints - http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/client/management .

There are a variety of ways to optimize this, such as via a write set, but based on your question, I think the first thing to decide is - what kind of document do you want to write for each Record? Your example shows 5 columns in the CSV - typically, you'll write either a JSON or XML document with 5 fields/elements, each named based on the column index. So you'd need to write a little code to generate that JSON/XML, and then use whatever HTTP client you prefer (and one option is the MarkLogic Java Client API) to write that document to MarkLogic.

That addresses your question of how to write a JavaRDD to MarkLogic - but if your goal is to get data from a CSV into MarkLogic as fast as possible, then skip Spark and use mlcp - https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_70366 - which involves zero coding.

Comment: I have updated my question, added the code for java client api to write  into marklogic database. I am writing the record as XML data. But getting the exception : sparkexception task not Serializable. Not able to figure out reason for the exception. If you have any clue please let me know. Also, the way i am writing to database if not correct then suggest me THE ONE.

Comment: There are multiple methods in the Java Client API for writing a document or a set of documents, and for this example, "writeAs" is perfectly fine.

Comment: To isolate the problem to DatabaseClient not being Serializable, I recommend not using JAXBContext, and just do something very simple like creating a String of XML and then writing that via a StringHandle. If that works, then you know the issue is with JAXB and some class not being Serializable. If that doesn't work, then the issue is with DatabaseClient, and I think Sam Mefford's suggestion below with a static reference to a DatabaseClient is a good thing to try.

Answer (score 0):

Modified example from [spark streaming guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd), Here you will have to implement connection and writing logic specific to database.

```
public void send(JavaRDD<String> rdd) {
    rdd.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<String>>() {
      @Override
      public void call(Iterator<String> partitionOfRecords) {
        // ConnectionPool is a static, lazily initialized pool of
        Connection connection = ConnectionPool.getConnection();
        while (partitionOfRecords.hasNext()) {
          connection.send(partitionOfRecords.next());
        }
        ConnectionPool.returnConnection(connection); // return to the pool
        // for future reuse
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Your answer is not clearly saying how i can write data to marklogic database. Can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: How can i create the connectionPool for marklogic database?

Comment: Please see https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/intro It has example on writing to MarkLogic. Hope that helps.

Comment: I know marklogic java api to write into marklogic. what i want to do is to write the data to marklogic using spark api. Example which you gave, if that could help in writing the data to marklogic database then my first question will be how do i have to create the connection object specific to marklogic which is there in the example.

Comment: The Connection and ConnectionPool are just example classes (and not concrete class or part of Spark API). You will have to write your own classes which has similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you just need to make sure everything you access inside your VoidFunction that was instantiated outside it is serializable (see [this page](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/javaionotserializableexception.html)).  DatabaseClient and XMLDocumentManager are of course not serializable, as they're connected resources.  You're right, however, to not instantiate DatabaseClient inside your VoidFunction as that would be less efficient (though it would work).  I don't know if the following idea would work with spark.  But I'm guessing you could create a class that keeps hold of a singleton DatabaseClient instance:

```
public static class MLClient {
  private static DatabaseClient singleton;
  private MLClient() {}

  public static DatabaseClient get(DatabaseClientFactory.Bean connectionInfo) {
    if ( connectionInfo == null ) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("connectionInfo cannot be null");
    }
    if ( singleton == null ) {
      singleton = connectionInfo.newClient();
    }
    return singleton;
  }
}
```

then you just create a serializable DatabaseClientFactory.Bean outside your VoidFunction so your auth info is still centralized

```
DatabaseClientFactory.Bean connectionInfo = 
  new DatabaseClientFactory.Bean();
connectionInfo.setHost("localhost");
connectionInfo.setPort(8000);
connectionInfo.setUser("admin");
connectionInfo.setPassword("admin");
connectionInfo.setAuthenticationValue("digest");
```

Then inside your VoidFunction you could get that singleton DatabaseClient and new XMLDocumentManager like so:

```
DatabaseClient client = MLClient.get(connectionInfo);
XMLDocumentManager docMgr = client.newXMLDocumentManager();
```

Comment: Thanks Sam for your answer.I know serializing database client is not advisable though but it's spark's VoidFunction which require all the resources has to be serialized. Actually i was looking for connector for marklogic with spark but didn't found any, so tried java client api itself with spark.